# Silverlight localization bug?

Tags: .net, silverlight, localization

I have a very weird problem, which looks like it could be a Silverlight bug. I have reproduced this in a simple application created from VS2010, Silverlight Application project default template.

In the app I have two .resx files, "Strings.resx" and "Strings.de.resx". They each have one key "SomeString", like so:

Strings.resx - SomeString - "some test string"

Strings.de.resx - SomeString - "some DE test string"

On the single application MainPage.xaml I just slapped a TextBlock, which I use in code like so, in the MainPage's class constructor:

```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
   txt.Text = Strings.SomeString;

   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
   txt.Text = Strings.SomeString;
```

Stepping through this with the debugger shows txt.Text to be "some DE test string" first and then "some test string". So everything works as it should.

HOWEVER, i installed the German language pack on my machine. Now, if I change, in the machine's Regional Settings, the system language to "Deutsch" and logoff/logon for the changes to take effect, the same code works differently: the SAME string "some DE test string" is retrieved from the resources TWICE. Basically, the second setting of the current culture/uiculture to "en-US" does nothing and the German string is still retrieved.

So in effect, if I want to have an app where the user can change the display language independently of the system launguage, I can't do it, because the incorrect resources are retrieved.

Again, in the case when the Windows OS Language is set to English, everything works correctly, I can change the culture and it works, correct string resources are loaded. When the Windows OS Language is set to Deutsch (haven't checked for others) I am unable to load the english string resources.

The problem manifests itself on both Vista and Windows 7 machines, haven't tested on others.

ps: the csproj file is changed to have `<SupportedCultures>en,en-US,de,de-DE</SupportedCultures>`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue comes from the default culture of your silverlight assembly: Did you recompile the App after having changed Windows culture from en to de?

Try to check the assembly neutral culture, and set is manually:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```

in the  assemblyInfo.cs file

Comment: You are right and adding this attribute solves the problem partially. By this I mean it works for every page except the FIRST page of the (bigger) app. For the first page the behavior is unchanged, attribute or not. Any idea why that might be? As a note, I actually have the culture specific .resx files in another xap that I'm loading dynamically on demand. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Also just to clarify: by first page i mean whichever page gets displayed first, it's not always the same one.

Comment: have you set the neutral resource language on all the assemblies?

Comment: Yes i have. In the meantime I've done a "workaround": I moved all my resx strings to the main assembly. Although I pay a penalty in xap size (about 20k) it works.

Comment: BUT, I've another problem: I've some keys/values only in the .de.resx files. If the CurrentUICulture is set to en-US getting the values for those keys, it again behaves differently depending on the OS language. If the OS language is English I get an empty string (correct, since the resources are only in the DE resource).  However, if the OS language is Deutsch, even tho' CurrentUICulture is en-US, I gets the string from the .de.resx. This shouldn't happen I think, It should always get an empty string, long as the CurrentUICulture is en-US and the NeutralResourcesLanguage is to en-US. Ideas?

Comment: For me, I had to set the assembly neutral language attribute of the assembly that housed the .resx files. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. What fixed it for me, is that I didn't rely on Silverlight guessing the correct neutral language. My app translates to en, de, fr and it. So i did (in every project I have localizable strings):

```
GuiStrings.resx
GuiStrings.en.resx
GuiStrings.de.resx
GuiStrings.fr.resx
GuiStrings.it.resx
```

This fixes the weird issue, that Silverlight ignores the neutral language ('en') on german machines.

Comment: Is your default resource then just empty and you have all your languages defined with GuiStrings.X.resx? Is this really the only solution to this problem?